# Select box related to another one using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I'd like to apply the example **Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms** in the documentation to create ans select box related to another one using Ajax. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

I have created all entities **SportMeetup**, **Sport** and **Positions**. I have also created all relations.
Right now I can display the form and all sports are displayed correctly in the select box but the code ajax is not working yet.

**Entity Sport** is related to Postion

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Position", mappedBy="sport", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $positions;
```

**Entity Position** is related to Sport

```
  /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Sport", inversedBy="positions", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $sport;
```

**Entity SportMeetup** is related to Sport and position

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Sport")
 */
private $sport;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Position")
 */
private $position;
```

**SportMeetupType**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
//........
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Sport;

class SportMeetupType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name','text')
        ->add('sport', 'entity', array(
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Sport',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'property'    => 'name',
            'attr'        => array('id'=>'meetup_sport')
        ));

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Sport $sport = null) {
        $positions = null === $sport ? array() : $sport->getPostions();

        $form->add('position', 'entity', array(
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Position',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices'     => $positions,
            'property'    => 'name',
            'attr'        => array('id'=>'meetup_position')
        ));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
            $data = $event->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getSport());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('sport')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $sport = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $sport);
        }
    );
}


public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SportMeetup'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'sportmeetup';
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function createAction(Request $request)
{

    $meetup = new SportMeetup();
    $form = $this->createForm(new SportMeetupType(), $meetup);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // ... save the meetup, redirect etc.
    }

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $id = $request->request->get('id');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $positions = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Position')->findBySport($id);

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(json_encode($positions));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render(
        'AppBundle:Dashboard/Sport-meetup:create.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

And this is the **form.twig**

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

    <label for="form-field-mask-2">Name</label>

    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}

    <br/>

    <label for="form-field-mask-2">Sport</label>

    {{ form_row(form.sport) }}

    <br/>

    <label>Position</label>

    {{ form_row(form.position) }}

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <br><br>
    <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm radius-4"> <i
                class='icon-remove bigger-110'></i>&nbsp; Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Send <i
                class="icon-arrow-right icon-on-right bigger-110"></i></button>

</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $sport = $('#meetup_sport');
// When sport gets selected ...
$sport.change(function () {
    // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
    var data = {};
    data[$sport.attr('name')] = $sport.val();
    // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('dashboard_sport_meetup_new') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (html) {
            // Replace current position field ...
            $('#meetup_position').replaceWith(
                    // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                    $(html).find('#meetup_position')
            );
            // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the problem ? it's client side or server side ? an error message will help to identify the source of the problem.

Comment: @zizoujab  Thank you for your attention , problem is solved , I'll make a post latter

Comment: @hous how did you solve the problem ?

Comment: @lepix. I have followed the example in the doc. what error you got ?